# Weird Android Service not starting

Tags: android, android-service

I have a weird issue with my Service not starting. I have my manifest file with the service, and have called it. But still it does not open up.

```
<service
android:name=".com.taxeeta.ForHire"
android:enabled="true" />
```

Calling the intent

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("com.taxeeta.ForHire");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Service

```
public class ForHire extends Service
```

I wonder what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call **startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ForHire.class));**

Every thing is fine in your menifest.

No need to set Action according to your menifest.

Comment: downvote? really? this is the right answer, unlike the others

Comment: ooops, you actually forgot to create an `Intent`. But the idea is right

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
android:name=".com.taxeeta.ForHire"
```

with

```
android:name="com.taxeeta.ForHire"
```

or if the service is on the root package

```
android:name=".ForHire"
```

Also, you should use [Intent.setClass( )](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) instead of setAction, since you don't have an IntentFilter declared for your service and you most likely, trying to use an explicit intent.

Answer (score 2):

When you Declare **service** in Manifest file use like this.

```
<service android:name=".ForHire">
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.taxeeta.ForHire" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

& call service Like this way.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction("com.taxeeta.ForHire");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

For More information about **Service** refer this Documentation
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the declaration of the service in your manifest. Change it to:

```
<service android:name="com.taxeeta.ForHire" />
```

(notice the `.` [dot] removed). Also make sure `service` is a child element of your `application` element, which is a must for the service to be recognized by the Android OS.